# AWS SDK for Java : How to get AWS Workspaces bundle options?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-java-2.0, amazon-workspaces

I am using AWS SDK for Java 2.X and have been trying to get workspace bundle compute type options but couldnt find any method that can provide the same.

The model class for the same is documented at https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.1.3/software/amazon/awssdk/services/workspaces/model/ComputeType.html and the types on AWS console are

1. Value
2. Standard
3. Performance
4. Power
5. Power Pro
6. GPU Enabled

Has anyone been able to retrieve that list using SDK? The Web end point to get this list is https://.console.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/service?operation=describeBundles

I tried SDK method to describe bundles (describeWorkspaceBundles) but this describes existing bundles and not the available compute type options.

If it helps, i am building the client like the following

```
workSpacesClient = WorkSpacesClient.builder()
                    .overrideConfiguration(getClientOverrideConfiguration())
                    .credentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                    .region(awsRegion)
                    .build();
```

And i was hoping for some client method to provide me the following list that we see on aws console

[Bundle compute types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVbJg.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.